# Lubuntu cannot run youtube

Tags: youtube

I have lubuntu 12.04 working alongside with windows xp on an old computer. Every time i go to youtube it does't respond. It doesn't even go to the page, but keeps loading.

Please help me!

Comment: Did you try later again? What about other web pages? What is the output when you open up a terminal and type in "ping 8.8.8.8"? What about "ping www.youtube.com"?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install or update:

- (Adobe) Flash player (in Synaptic / Software Center under flashplugin-installer or flashplugin or adobe flash player, any of those should find it)
- a web browser that can do HTML5 (like Firefox or Chromium or Opera) and try telling youtube to try to use HTML5 first ( at this page https://www.youtube.com/html5 )

If you're using the Adobe Flash player, these Adobe pages have some tests & tips, they're at least good pages to see if your flash player works:

- https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/
- http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

That is all assuming you have a working internet connection and can load other plain websites.